# Android replace fragment or launch new activity with fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am still unsure of best design practices using fragments. I've looked at the dev docs at:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

There seems to be two ways that a new screen can be made, in a single pane layout at least. Let's say I have a button inside one fragment and I want it to show a new view when clicked. Should I be using the original activity and replace with a FragmentTransaction or should I have the original activity launch an intent to a new activity that displays that fragment. I am pretty sure both can work. I'm more wondering about design practice. Or should I use a dialogfragment?

If it matters, the second fragment needs to pass information back to the original fragment at some point.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is return some data to the fragment I would probably use Dialog.

However, for switching fragments, its much better to use a FragmentTransaction to change Fragments, that way you don't need a new Activity (one of the main positives of using Fragments).